# DispatcherPriority.Render vs DispatcherPriority.Loaded

Tags: wpf

I'm quite new to WPF.

I'm experiencing flickering issues when drawing pictures using DirectX in combination with a UniformGrid located in an ItemsControl.
The flickering occurs when adding or removing a new HwndHost to/from the UserControl.

To address this problem, I've started using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render) for DirectX rendering, which somewhat alleviate the symptoms.

Now, I have a couple of questions:

Question 1.
Based on the explanation 'DispatcherPriority Enum',
I expect Loaded event to be called after DispatcherPriority.Render priority function is processed. However, why is the Loaded event called before DispatcherPriority.Render priority function?

Question 2.
I added a event handler to Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationStarted and included Debug.WriteLine statement in it. Surprisingly, Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationStarted is not called before the Loaded event is processed. How is this possible?

Here's the complete code snippet I'm using for testing:

Currently, the output is 'Grid_Loaded' followed by 'DX11Render.' However, I expect it to be 'DX11Render' and then 'Grid_Loaded.'

Furthermore, I expected 'Hooks_OperationStarted' to be printed before 'Grid_Loaded,' but it doesn't occur as anticipated.

I expects 'Hooks_OperationStarted' to be printed before 'Grid_Loaded' is printed but it does not.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationPosted += Hooks_OperationPosted;
        Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationStarted += Hooks_OperationStarted;
        Dispatcher.Hooks.OperationCompleted += Hooks_OperationCompleted;

        InitializeComponent();

        Grid grid = new Grid();
        grid.Loaded += Grid_Loaded;
        AddChild(grid);
        Dispatcher?.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, new DispatcherOperationCallback(DX11Render), null);
    }

    private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Grid_Loaded");
    }
    private void Hooks_OperationStarted(object sender, DispatcherHookEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Operation.Priority == DispatcherPriority.Loaded)
            Debug.WriteLine($"Hooks_OperationStarted {e.Operation.Priority}");
    }
    private void Hooks_OperationPosted(object sender, DispatcherHookEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Operation.Priority == DispatcherPriority.Loaded)
            Debug.WriteLine($"Hooks_OperationPosted {e.Operation.Priority}");
    }
    private void Hooks_OperationCompleted(object sender, DispatcherHookEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Operation.Priority == DispatcherPriority.Loaded)
            Debug.WriteLine($"Hooks_Hooks_OperationCompleted {e.Operation.Priority}");
    }
    private object DX11Render(object state)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DX11Render");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Loaded is raised when the FrameworkElement was measured and arranged, all bindings were resolved and the rendering surface is ready. Loaded in addition ios raised when the complete logical tree is ready in terms of previously mentioned steps. In other words, Loaded is raised when the FrameworkElement is ready for rendering, hence before the actual rendering of the FrameworkElement. Your observations don't lie. You just have a wrong idea on how WPF is working.

Comment: .NET API reference: *"Typically, this event is due to the BeginInvoke API, but the Invoke API can also cause this event if any priority other than DispatcherPriority.Send is specified, or if the destination dispatcher is owned by a different thread."* - The docs clearly state that the event is usually raised when operations are asynchronously invoked (i.e invocation is deferred). All dispatcher operations required to load the FrameworkElement are synchronous dispatcher operations.

Comment: After the Loaded event the FrameworkElement can receive or process input events. This is when asynchronous dispatcher operations or operations with a lower priority than DispatcherPriority.Send take over (because now the high priority loading and rendering is completed).

Comment: @BionicCode. Thank you for your comments. I'm reading your comments again and again to understand them. BTW, what's 'in addition ios' in your first comment?

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. "ios" was supposed to be "is": _"Loaded in addition __is__ raised when the complete logical tree is ready in terms of previously mentioned steps. In other words, Loaded is raised when the FrameworkElement is ready for rendering, hence before the actual rendering of the FrameworkElement."_

Comment: Loaded is executed when the FramworkElement is completely initialized and therefore ready for rendering (in accordance with the FramworkElement.Loaded event). Render of course is executed when the FrameworkElement is rendered. And because you call Dispatcher?.BeginInvoke  you are posting the work asynchronously to the Dispatcher. This means it will execute after all of the currently enqueued jobs are completed and therefore it executes last in the current context.